# using SDL_Texture* on several SDL_Renderers*

Tags: c++, window, sdl-2, renderer

I'm trying to use the same SDL_Texture* on two separate SDL_Renderer*, but apparently SDL_Texture seems to be "tied" to a SDL_Renderer*.
Is there a way to make the second renderer able to use the texture created through SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface using the first renderer? If i try doing so by just copying the SDL_Texture* pointer and using SDL_RenderCopy with the second renderer, the screen stays black.

If more details are needed:
I'm using the SDL2 library in Virtual Studio. I have two separate SDL_Window's, each with one SDL_Renderer. The window containing the first renderer is permanently existen through the whole program, while the second window is only created, when needed and destroyed shortly after.

Comment: Why not use two `SDL_Texture`s?

Comment: I try to keep the redundancy low, because as my program grows, using 2 SDL_Texture's would take up a huge amount of space.

Comment: You said that the second window is destroyed shortly after its creation. Creating a texture for the renderer associated to that window and destroying it with the window wouldn't hurt your memory usage. It does affect the performance, since you would need to copy the source surface once more, but it wouldn't cost much compared to the creation of a window.

Comment: That's true but i create all my textures using a single surface, which is long freed, when i create the second window. I could write a work around to load in the surface again, but that'd be rather unpleasant to write and could lead to some weird errors, when the source fail is changed, while my program runs. That's why i ask if there's an easy way for this.

Comment: Am I to understand that the proper way to use bitmap font textures in multiple windows in SDL 2 is to create a separate set of textures for each window that the bitmap font textures will be used in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if it's the most straightforward way, but you could copy your texture to an SDL_Surface, and then at the other end use SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface.

Comment: That would be an ok solution, since my problem is memory critical, but not really time critical at this point, but I can't find a way to convert a SDL_Texture to a SDL_Surface.

Comment: @a_familiar_wolf that could be problematic. You can use `SDL_RenderReadPixels` (don't forget to set texture as render target first, and then reset it) but it requires your texture to be created with `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET` flag. If you can, reloading image from original file looks a better solution.

Comment: Not so problematic, albeit slow: Assuming you did, indeed, create your texture as @keltar advised and created an SDL_Surface, `surf`, you do a `SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, &surf->clip_rect, surf->format->format, surf->pixels, surf->pitch)` to get the pixels into your surface. Afterwards, a simple `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surf)` should yield the SDL_Texture.

Comment: @baueran I don't think it is that simple, but that depends on rendering backend. E.g. in that particular case it may be unknown at the time of texture creation if it will be needed in another renderer, so one might end up with marking _all_ textures as render targets. That may have non-zero cost (e.g. allocting FBO for each texture with GL/GLES renderers), driver may put texture in different memory region that could affect rendering performance, but most of all - 'target' textures are not required to keep its contents upon device loss with d3d renderer (e.g. switch to fullscreen).